# Where to place code not directly related to a view (such as ads, analytics etc) in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, structure

I am building a backbone.js application, and as far as my understanding, each backbone "class" is intended to do the following:

- **Model**: the object representation of your data, ie the result of hitting an API would get stored in a model.
- **Collection**: An ordered set of models, ie if you had a "book" model, you could have a collection of all models representing "science fiction" books.
- **Router**: routes page URL's to actions/events, ie 'site.com/help' routes to a `help: funciton(){}`
- **View**: The visual representation of a model, rendering to the DOM.

This leaves me uncertain as to where I should place my "generic" code, such as analytics and ad scripts, helper functions, tracking, etc.

What is the appropriate convention for these sort of things? Would I place them into a backbone view (even if they don't contain any page-renderable content)? Do I need to use a module loader like Browserify or Require.js? I would like to avoid getting those involved as the project is small and I don't need additional library overhead.

Comment: You need not use a `View` in such cases. You can use a modulo pattern to define your generics. maybe one file for each. And then return the object and use the properties of returned function. Also using `require` in your case makes more sense. Does not matter if your project is small or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"What is the appropriate convention for these sort of things?"

Splitting your code in module is a good practice. Use a module pattern or use requirejs to build modules.

Check the module pattern here http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: I want to do well could you explain what would be an answer ? The guy need to build modules how is it not an answer telling him he needs to build module in separate files using a module pattern or requirejs ?

Comment: I'm interested in ways to do it without having an additional script (module loaders). What did people do to solve this problem in the pre-requirejs days? :) My next project will use a module loader, but for this current one we need an alternative structure.

Comment: have you check the module pattern ? no module loader needed.